What to do when copilot and captain have a contradiction in a critical situation?
There have been multiple accidents where there is conflict of thinking inside the cockpit between the captain and co-pilot which have lead to unfortunate outcomes due to the critical phase of the flight at which the conflict has happened(i.e. in landing/takeoff or in something like in a low altitude warning flying in IMC).
Watching the documentaries of these accidents, I see a repetitive pattern in particular, and is that usually the copilot was right in the thinking but due to seniority of the captain mixed with the stressful situation the copilot is "ignored" and the captain takes the wrong decision leading to an unfortunate outcome.
What's the best thing to do in a situation like this?
Are there any companies that have some procedures written for this?
Have you experienced something like this and were you able to get out of it without any incident?
Is there something written from the FAA/EASA/ICAO regarding this conflict resolution and specifically on critical time situation like this where a quick action is needed?

Probable duplicates (not an exhaustive list): https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/100406/7532 and https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46779/7532

Just get a book on Crew Resource Management and start reading.
